# Count the occurrence of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++

I just recently created a code in C++ where I have to display the occurrence of numbers from a text file that I made using this code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    bool isCovered[99] = {};
    int number;


    // Read each number and mark its corresponding element covered
    while (cin.good())
{
    cin >> number;
    if (number == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ((number >= 1) && (number <= 99))
    {
        isCovered[number - 1] = true;
    }
}


    // Check if all covered
    bool allCovered = true; // Assumes all covered initially
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        if (!isCovered[i])
        {
            allCovered = false; //Finds one number not covered
            break;
        }
    // Display result
    if (allCovered)
     cout << "The tickets cover all numbers" << endl;
    else
     cout << "The tickets don't cover all numbers" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's not displaying a result, is the program too complex, or is it something that I'm missing?

EDIT: Thanks @selbie for the edit to my code, i was able to figure out that it was a user input but when i put in a zero for the final input. It displays the messages "The tickets don't cover all numbers", why is that?

Comment: You don't need a loop to initialize all items in `isCovered` to false.  You can simply declare `bool isCovered[99] = {};`

Comment: If you need to count the number of occurrences it would make more sense to hold an array of integers so that `count[number - 1]` will give you the frequency of `number`. And just do `count[number-1]++` to count.

Comment: I get perfectly sensible results when I run that program.  Exactly what input did you give it?

Comment: Adding onto abelenky's comment, example output that you are seeing alongside the output you expect to see would be helpful in determining the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Alright @selbie, i went and removed the ```// Initialize the array``` part and added the ```{}``` but repl.it is still showing a blank result.

Comment: Ok @0x499602D2, @abelenky, i was able to input the numbers into the ```{}``` but it came up with this error message: ```main.cpp:7:41: error: constant expression
      evaluates to 45 which cannot be
      narrowed to type 'bool'
      [-Wc++11-narrowing]
  ...= {5, 78, 8, 9, 70, 45, 8};``` what could it mean? I'm still learning C++ as a student.

Comment: If you type any number into your input stream greater than `99`, you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: @BigPete `{5, 78, 8, 9, 70, 45, 8}` -- Where did this new code come from?  Also, as suggested, you need to check if anything greater than 99 is entered

Comment: What do you mean by not displaying anything? Is console blank? What is the input?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i have a series of numbers in a text file that i'm trying to get the program to run. But they are not puncuated (basically without commas).

Comment: Pete, are you manually typing your numbers into the console to test, or are you using file redirection (ala:  `program.exe < input.txt` ) ?

Comment: @BigPete In your comment, you highlighted the error as if that text is within your code.  All you were told to do is `bool isCovered[99] = {};`

Comment: Then, problem could be the reading file or somewhere else. Please provide [minimum reproducible exams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4139593)

Comment: @selbie i'm not too sure. I'll see if i can keep messing around with it.

Comment: This sounds like a task for `std::map` or even just `std::set`, rather than an array

Answer (score 1):

The bug, if any, is here:

```
cin >> number;
while (number != 0)
{
    isCovered[number - 1] = true;
    cin >> number;
}
```

Two possible issues:

1. If reading from a redirected file, there's no detection of an end-of-file condition.  Such would be the case if the program was invoked as `program.exe < input.txt` and the `input.txt` did not contain a `0`.  Without checking for eof, the program will hang when reading from an input file redirection.
2. Further, there's nothing to guard against bad input.  i.e. numbers outside the range of `[1..99]`.  Without guarding against out of range numbers, undefined behavior will get introduced.  Or more likely, the stack will get trashed as a result of inserting into a memory address out of range.

The easy fix is this:

```
while (cin.good())
{
    cin >> number;
    if (number == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ((number >= 1) && (number <= 99))
    {
        isCovered[number - 1] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ` // Read each number and mark its corresponding element covered
 while (cin.good())
{
    cin >> number;
    if (number == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ((number >= 1) && (number <= 99))
    {
        isCovered[number - 1] = true;
    }
}`
So, i was able to change it but didn't realize that i had to manually input my numbers in the system, lol, i also noticed that when i put `0` in for my final input it gave me `cout << "The tickets don't cover all numbers" << endl;`